# Slow queries from commandline mysql and from PHP script but fast from phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am using XAMPP server (PHP Version 7.0.9 and Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.0.9 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 ). When I try to query database through through php it take more than 30 second but through phpmyadmin it takes only fraction of second. My database is huge(23000 records), help me in configuring where does the problem lies.

Comment: Uhm, why are you accessing it via the cmd line anyway? Use SequelPro or Workbench

Comment: Problem lies in assuming that we can guess your query, your tables, your indexes, etc.... but consider that phpmyadmin is probably returning a subset of the query results because paging; then look at your query and consider indexing the tables in an appropriate manner, or at least running an EXPLAIN to see how the query is being executed

Comment: PS. 23000 records isn't huge; it's pretty tiny

Comment: I have not used and indexes so far. I am also using paging through jquery online.